# Adding different classes with different extensions to Androidmanifest.xml

Tags: android, variables, global-variables

I am only new to android and have a number of classes which extend AppCompatActivity and one GlobalClass to create global variables extending Application. When I add the 'GlobalClass' to the android manifest it doesn't allow it because it extends Application and not AppCompactActivity. Could anyone tell me how to fix it? Thank you for your help.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.almac.tracker">

<application
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
        android:name=".Dashboard"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".CreateLine">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".VerifyLine">
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".Actforfragmentname">
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".GlobalClass">
    </activity>
</application>
```

GlobalClass - extends Application

```
public class GlobalClass extends Application{

private String name;
public String getName(){
    return name;
}

public void setName(String Name){
    name = Name;
}
```

Comment: `android:name=".GlobalClass "` in `<application` tag , it's not an activity

Comment: Thank you very much Pavneet_Singh !

Comment: i am glad that i could help, happy coding

Answer (score 0):

GlobalClass is an Application , not an activity.

```
     <application
    android:name=".GlobalClass"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Answer (score 0):

`GlobalClass` is an `Application` Class , you have add this in application tag like below code

```
 <application
   android:name=".GlobalClass"<!-- add here your GlobalClass is an Application Class -->
   android:label="@string/app_name"
   android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
   android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```